# Importing Dictionary from One Jupyter Notebook to Another (Gurobi)

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gurobi

I am new to programming and learning Python as my first programming language in a course that uses Gurobi Optimization software. If my terms are a little off, I apologize but, as I said, I am very new to this and this is my first attempt at posting.

I have pulled data from an Excel file into a Jupyter Notebook using a code that was written by the professor (not using pandas). The data file is stored as a dictionary in a Jupyter Notebook, which I'll call 'Notebook A'. I need to use the dictionary from 'Notebook A' in 'Notebook B' as the data file when executing the code in 'Notebook B'. Is there a way to call a dictionary FROM 'Notebook A' from within 'Notebook B'?

There are actually two dictionaries in 'Notebook A', titled 'itemsInfo' and 'demands'. A *very small section of code* that reads in the Excel file and stores it into the two dictionaries in 'Notebook A' is listed below. The full code for reading in the complex Excel file is quite long.

```
itemsInfo, demands = read_data("IE522_Input_File_v2.xls")
items = itemsInfo.keys()
```

The first dictionary lists the four (4) keys: `(['Key 1','Key 2','Key 3','Key 4'])`,
for example:`(['10009','10010','10011','10012'])`

The second dictionary lists the items tied to each key, such that: `{('Key',week):demand`
for example: `('10010',1):2,('10010',1):5,(10009',2):3,(10009,2,10),....)}`

Please let me know how I would pull the dictionaries from 'Notebook A', which have been pulled from the Excel file, into 'Notebook B' so I can use that data in the newly written code held within 'Notebook B'. I am not familiar with how to use the function such as 'init' or 'classes'.

I have tried using `gp.multidict({ })` but that doesn't seem right b/c it is a larger data set and part of the assignment is to avoid typing the data manually.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to use separate notebooks, I would use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to write the dictionary to a file with Notebook A and read that in Notebook B.

Notebook A:

```
import pickle

mydict = {
    'Key 1': 10009,
    'Key 2': 10010,
    'Key 3': 10011,
    'Key 4': 10012,
}

with open('keys.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(mydict, f)
```

Notebook B:

```
import pickle

with open('keys.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    newdict = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'll try this and see if I can get it to work.